# How to make a loop x in python, attribute a value to a variable and print this value each time?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to ask the user how many times the loop has to be made and inside the loop, put a value in a variable and then print all the values in the loop.

```
x = int(input("Number of loops: "))

for y in range(x):
 z = str(input())
 print (z)
```

If the user types "2" i want the loop to happen 2 times and each time ask for a name to (z) and then print all the names I gave to z, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you want, do you want to print all the input to `z` ?

```
x = int(input("Number of loops: "))
z = []
for y in range(x):
    z.append(str(input()))
print(z)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly that, care to explain me about this code? Why use "[]"? I don't understand why i don't put any value in z

Comment: "[]" means `list` in python, it can store the each input you typed. In your code, `z` will be covered every time.